# Array of calendar objects

Tags: java, android

Can one create an array of calendar objects?

If yes, how does one do so? This code surely gives error

```
Calendar cal[length];     
//loop for initialising all the objects in cal[] array
```

If no, what other way is there for getting "n" number of calendar objects?
I need this for a repeating alarm, set at different times.

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to use one calender, and then assign to dates?

Comment: ...You don't initialize arrays like that in Java.  You do in C, though...

Comment: @Xaade are you suggesting to use multiple date objects?

Comment: Store data in date objects, and use calendars to interact with more complex fields, like day of week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always do `Calendar[] cal = new Calendar[length];`

You can use an ArrayList, too, such as:

`List<Calendar> list = new ArrayList<Calendar>();`

Then there's a lot of convenience methods, such as `add(Calendar calendar);`

Then:

You can use `for (int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++)`

or `for (Calendar cal : list)`

This is valid for the array, too. Inside the for you use `getCalendar()` or `new GregorianCalendar()` or whatever `Calendar` you need.

Comment: But we always initialize calendar objects using getInstance?...or i can do that using for(int i =0; int<length; length++){ cal[i]=Calendar.getInstance()}?

Comment: @tanvi You can and you should.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to use `java.util.Timer` and `java.util.TimerTask` to arrange a repeating alarm:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

t.schedule(
    new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("alarm1");
        }
    },
    c.getTime());
```

Comment: can I use this timer to call another activity at a specified time?

Answer (score 1):

Calendar cal[] = new Calendar[100];

Answer (score 0):

Take a look ath this [document site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) of Java. There you can find out how to use arrays and the example is very useful. In fact you only need to change the `int` to `Calendar` in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar` is `abstract` class. So you should initialize `Calendar` variable/array with some subclass, which is not abstract. For example:

```
Calendar[] calendars = new Calendar[1];
calendars[0] = new GregorianCalendar();
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax for creating an array in Java is:

Calendar[] cal = new Calander[length];

Then you can initialze the individual elements.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the better solution is use code like this:

```
ArrayList<Calendar> list = new ArrayList<Calendar>();
```

Now use a loop logic with this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

use cal to set value & the add it in ArrayList :)

This is because it will give you the power of adding/removing items dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Calendar[] calendars = new Calendar[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        calendars[i] = Calendar.getInstance();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, objects are not allocated unless you use the `new` keyword. This is unlike C++ where new is only used to allocate memory dynamically. To achieve what you are trying to do, do:

```
Calendar cal[] = new GregorianCalendar[length];
```

You may find these links helpful:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Also, in Java, Lists are usually used in preference to arrays, because they are much more convenient to work with and contain most of the functions you will most likely need for access and manipulation. Use a List as follows:

```
List<Calendar> calendars = new ArrayList<Calendar>();
for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    calendars.add(myCalendar);
}
```